# Select date from timestamp in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy with python and i want to select date from column type timestamp, to do this query:

```
SELECT DATE(`record_date`) FROM Users
```

I made this code by sql alchemy but it will return the timestamp:

```
session.query(Users.record_date).all()
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

give an alias

```
  SELECT DATE(`record_date`) as record_d FROM Users
```

then use this

```
 session.query(Users.record_d).all()
```

If want do it directly then ,try this

```
your_dates = session.query(cast(Users.record_date, DATE)).all()
```

EDIT:

```
your_dates = session.query(func.DATE(Users.record_date)).all()
```

Comment: I want to do it direct from sqlalchemy

Comment: i want to do it in this line session.query(Users.record_date).all()

Comment: Thaanks, it's better answer :)