# Formating Columns in add_columns in Sql Alchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an application that uses SQL Alchemy for my SQL wherein a table I have `DateTime` fields.

```
data = my_table.query.join(
    master_table, master_table.id == my_table.master_table_id
).add_columns(
    my_table.created_by,
    my_table.created_on,
    master_table.created_on
)
```

Now when I query on the following columns then I need to fetch only the date from `created_on` columns. But not want to query on these columns.

Any Idea how it can be done.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30251777/sqlalchemy-convert-datetime-column-to-date-column, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114106/select-date-from-timestamp-in-sqlalchemy, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773279/sqlalchemy-applying-an-sql-like-date-function-on-a-datetime-column ?

Comment: No But all the above examples consist of Date Conversion in filter with some match on Date i do not need to match the date with anything i need it as it is.

Comment: And you cant do the same conversion in your select list? "Now when I query on the following columns then I need to fetch only the date from created_on columns". In fact the second link does just that (not filter).